# MD5 code generation

Tags: iphone

I have a query regarding MD5 code generation. My page has 4 fields, like user name, password.

I need MD5 code generation for password fields. My MD5 code conversion code is perfect, there is no error, but when I run the application, it crashes.

I exactly don't know how to convert my password field with my conversion code. I need help as I am new to iPhone development. Code would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the code or part that you might thing there a problem.

Comment: That's what my programs are like too. They're perfect and bug free - until you run them !

Comment: Clearly your MD5 code is *not* perfect, or it wouldn't be crashing your app.  Please post it, if you want any sensible answers (i.e. we'll all have to guess, otherwise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this in the past. You might find it helpful.

```
- (NSString *)stringWithMD5Hash:(NSString *)inStr {
    const char *cStr = [inStr UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15] ];
}
```

This requires importing `CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h`.